# How to provide a user with progress or estimation of time to needed to complete a task

Tags: c#, .net, performance, xamarin, xamarin.forms

In my application, I am using a library to generate a .pdf extension document. This is a Xamarin.Forms application, thus it can be run from any iOS or Android OS running device. Now, the problem I have is reporting to the user the progress of the exporting process. Sometimes this can take 50 seconds, some times 4 minutes. It all depends on amount of data in the document and the device itself.

Now, it would be great if it would be a for loop that is running to generate the pdf where I could then simply iterate and display the progress. However, what I have now is a method provided by the library "Draw" which does all the "heavy lifting" and don't know if there is a way I could show the progress or at least an estimation of how long will it take to finish.

So to sum up, the question is, is there some sort of library, or a way that anyone has heard of to perhaps predict the estimated time to finish a task. Maybe a way to still show some sort of progress even if the method does not provide "steps of completion". Any suggestion is a good suggestion and are all appreciated.

Comment: If the library that you are using to `Draw` does not have some type of progress callback, and it is just that single method call, then you can not really give the user a "Determinate" type of process indictor, instead just display an "Indeterminate" indictor, perhaps with a count up timer  `0 to XXX` that updates the time (in seconds) it has taken so far as to give the user a pseudo UI feedback that something is actually happening in the app.

Comment: @SushiHangover thanks for the comment. I have already added a "spinner", but thought it also might be a good idea to do incremental time 0 to XXX as you say.

Comment: Do you know the amount of data in the document? Could you export a tiny test document before the real-big one, so that you can estimate the duration for the big based on the duration of the tiny?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias That's actually a good idea. Thanks!

Comment: Progress indicators are notorious in the programming world for never being accurate. Best to just avoid them altogether.

Comment: @TylerH But it doesn't need to be accurate, at least in my case. It is just there to show the user, that something is still happening and he/she should wait instead of throwing their phone to a wall ;)

Comment: You can check this link:  https://www.jimbobbennett.io/animating-xamarin-forms-progress-bars/

Answer (score 1):

You could make an estimation based on the amount of data in the document, and show a progress bar based on your estimation. The progress bar could be pessimistic so that at the time of estimated completion it will be at around 80% or something. In the worst case scenario the user will see the progress bar reach 100%, and then nothing happening, leading them to believe that the process has died. You could make visible a label with the text "Finalizing..." or something similar on 100%, to mitigate the user's concerns.

Another approach is to wrap on 100% and restart the progress bar from zero. This way the user may feel betrayed, but at least will be more confident that progress is still made.